# Xamarin.iOS - Cannot launch view controller on button click

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created a user interface (xib) using the designer in visual studio. The view has a pickerView and a button to submit the selected value. I am trying to load a new view controller once the button is clicked but cannot figure out how to access the button from within the current view controller. I can access the button from the views backing class, however from here I am unable to access the NavigationController in order to push the new view controller that I'm trying to load.  A push in the right direction would be most appreciated.  I am not using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. When I load the backing class for the view, I simply pass in the NavigationController of the current ViewController

```
CityPicker_View v;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        v = CityPicker_View.Create(this.NavigationController);
        this.View = v;
    }
```

Then in the backing class to pick up the NavigationController:

```
public static CityPicker_View Create(UINavigationController cont)
{ 
  UIcont = cont
  ...
  ...
}
```

Also, in the backing class, pick up the NavigationController that was passed over and use it to fire up the next ViewController on button click event

```
  partial void BtnSubmit_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender
   {
     var controller = new TabController();
     UIcont.PushViewController(controller, false);
   }
```